# Intermittent crash when I call C++ from C#

Tags: c#, c++, exception, dll, interop

I have a C++ API which I cam calling from C# and it crashes intermittently after running normally sometimes up to 5h.

The C++ side:

```
struct Doubles
{
    double d1
    double d2;
};

struct Package
{
    char name[20]{};
    int lenD1{};
    Doubles* d1;
    int lenD2{};
    Doubles* d2{};
    int64_t duration;
};

// Basically I am passing an array of Packages preallocated on C# side and let C++ to fill in
extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) int api(int packageLen, Package* pkg);
```

Here is what is on C# side:

```
struct Doubles
{
    public double d1;
    public double d2;
};

unsafe struct Package
{
    public fixed byte[20]; // here we use byte as char on C# is 2 bytes unlike C++ 
    public int lenD1;
    public unsafe Doubles* d1;
    public int lenD2;
    public unsafe Doubles* d2;
    long duration;
};

[DllImport("..path/api.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagesType.I4)]
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
public static extern int api([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] int len, Package* packages);

unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int len = 10;
    fixed(Package* pkgs = new Package[len]) // create the array of packages
    {
        for(int i=0; i<len;++i) // and allocate space for individual one for C++ to fill in the data
        {
            fixed(Doubles* d_1 = new Double[20])
            {
                fixed(Doubles* d_2 = new Double[20])
                {
                    pkgs[i].d1 = d_1;
                    pkgs[i].d2 = d_2;
                    pkgs[i].lenD1 = 20;
                    pkgs[i].lenD2 = 20;
                } 
            } 
        }

        while(true)
        {
            int res = api(len,pkgs); // res is number of pkgs filled in
            
            for(int k=0; k<res;++k)
            {
                string s = "";
                for(int j=0; j<20;++j)
                {
                    if(pkgs[i].name[k] == '\n'){break;}
                    s+=(char)pkgs[i].name[k]; // converting filled byte[] to string
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this randomly crashes after random period of time and always some error regarding corrupt memory.

[image]

Or

[image]

For instance something like aboves. I even tried to reset the previously used Pakcages in the array in the beginning of while loop but no results. I am a C++ guy digging in C# here tbh. There is no stack trace, line number no nothing, just crashing randomly after working for hours sometimes.

Note: C++ app meanwhile continues to run without any errors or exceptions.

Maybe someone is spotting something very obvious I am missing here or any suggestion how to debug or diagnose this?

Comment: You need to used Marshal techniques and the allocated memory has to be in unmanaged memory.  Not in c#..  Unless the c++ is managed code.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the fixed keyword takes care of it, i.e. it GC will not touch or move it @jdweng

Comment: I'm not too confident on this but wouldn't `d_1` and `d_2` become unpinned when you leave that execution block? Maybe try rearranging the code so they're on the outer level and the unmanaged API is called within those blocks.

Comment: The Doubles* pointers are not stable, a garbage collection will change them.  Without updating d1 and d2.  Just don't help, declare them as double[] in the struct.  It is very fast, the pinvoke marshaller takes care of the temporary pinning and passes a pointer.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. May I please ask why Package* inside fixed are stable and Double* are not?

Comment: Because its fixed statement spans the entire method body.

Comment: The fixed keyword just says the array size doesn't change.  Not where the array is located in memory.  Managed and unmangaged code does not run in the same memory space on the microcontroller.  Marshal is the only way of putting the data is the correct area of memory so microprocessor does fire alarms (interrupts)  which stop code from running.

Comment: @jdweng this isn't about putting in some pre arranged space. This is just making GC not to move it. And I think fixed is doing a little more than fixing array size or saying it will not change.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with GC.  There mcro is operating in protected mode where the are lots of memory sectors.  When you access the memory using the wrong sector you will get memory violations.  The memory sector in the c++ and c# are different.  So you can't use same memory space for both c++ and c#.  The Marshal class allow memory from c# to be put into c++ memory so you do not get memory exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Is using the 'i' variable in the 'j' loop in your C# code a deliberate choice?

```cs
for(int j=0; j<20;++j)
{
    if(pkgs[i].name[k] == '\n'){break;}
    //------^
    s+=(char)pkgs[i].name[k]; // converting filled byte[] to string
    //------------^
}
```